# Python: table lookup in a text file

Tags: python, awk, lookup

I am feeding a big csv file into a database. Two of the input fields are indexes, meant for consulting a conversion table in a separate lookup-table file. I could do this easily enough in awk:

```
RESULT = $(awk -v CODE=$FIELD8 '$1 == CODE {print $3}' $FILE_WITH_TABLE)
```

What would be the equivalent python code?
Should I read both files into arrays for speedier lookup (the one has 18379 bytes in 248 entries, the other 360653 bytes in 4113 entries)?

I found something about pythons hash function but see no way to apply it to this question.

Edited to add (as suggested) two lines of the main data file to be interpreted:

```
35313,"ZULZ","small_airport","Luzhou Airport",28.85219955444336,105.39299774169922,,"AS","CN","CN-51","Luzhou","yes","ZULZ","LZO",,,"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzhou_Airport",
308767,"ZUMH","small_airport","Öndörkhaan Airport",47.30486,110.6092,3410,"AS","MN","MN-039","Öndörkhaan","no","ZUMH","UNR",,,,"Undur Khan"
```

The 9th field (values "CN" and "MN") must be used to consult a table of countries by ISO code, here are the two corresponding lines from that file:

```
302627,"CN","China","AS","http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China",
302650,"MN","Mongolia","AS","http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolia",
```

and likewise the tenth field of the basic file is used to consult another table, with regions per country by ISO code this time. The intermediate output wanted is the input line, parsed into fields by csv.reader (no issues there) but with the 9th and 10th fields filled in with the values looked up ("China" and "Mongolia").
So if a directory is used, it would contain the second field from the aux file as a search index, and the third field as the data to be returned.

Omitting the other lookup to keep things clear, the mechanism is identical.

Comment: If you're looking for a hash table, they're called dictionaries in python: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries .  Also note that Python has CSV read/write as part of the standard library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: 't Is not that I am looking for "how to do a hash table" - I am wondering whether a hash table aka dictionary would be the right (or the best) solution to the given question.

Comment: what does the data look like?

Comment: Here's some samples of the data, the files are quite neat, csv.reader has no issues with them. Even the codepage is UTF-8, beyond hope.     Two lines from the main data file:    6529,"00CO","small_airport","Cass Field",40.62220001220703,-104.34400177001953,4830,"NA","US","US-CO","Briggsdale","no","00CO",,"00CO",,, The "US" field and the "US-CO" are to be looked up in separate text files: 302755,"US","United States","NA","http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States","America" 306081,"US-CO","CO","Colorado","NA","US","http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorado",

Comment: PS excuse me for the messy looks, I have no idea how to make the data appear neater. Source of the files is the "downloads" section of www dot our airports dot com

Comment: Perhaps I ought to point out that performance is not the first requirement: this is a job that is performed once per week or so, and whether it takes 20 minutes or 5 hours is not very relevant. More important is to have clear readable code, easy to understand and to maintain.

Comment: Edit your question to include the data, don't try to put it in a comment. Make sure you show clear, consistent sample input and expected output.

Comment: Your shell and Awk script snippet has a bug and several oddities, too.  The whitespace around the equals sign is a syntax error and the normal way to do this would be in Awk entirely, unless you need for the user to interact with the program in a loop, in which case you should probably be using a small database instead.

Comment: I could very well do this in awk, thank you, but for reasons of my own I decided to do it in python, and I do not wish to argue that choice. (Feel free however to point me to libraries for reading csv and writing mysql in awk). My question is "how to (best) do this in Python".